# Unable to move small window when making a phone call in Facetime on macOS 10.15.7

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, facetime

It is possible to make audio phone calls directly from macOS using the Facetime app and this works very well. Unfortunately a small Window is placed on the top/right counter of the screen and I cannot seem to be able to move or minimize this window. Has anyone an idea on how to customize the location of this window?

[image]

Comment: Are you making a video call or just audio?

Comment: just an audio call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't move or minimize the window that supports a call, it's a sort of static notification.

More people are annoyed by this:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8095870
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8085443?page=1

You can disable the notification via System Preferences > Notifications > Facetime by unticking "Badge app icon".

I do appreciate the notification to answer the call. Even though my MacBook has a touch bar which also allows me to Answer/End, Video or Mute. Also note the touch bar doesn't sport the button you need when you have to dial during a call ("Select 1 for department A, Select 2 for department B"). So, you'll need the pop-up.

You can kill the pop-up as documented over here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313721

(somebody even shared a script for the kill command using an Automator Applet)

Don't forget to provide Apple feedback on this. Even though it's been a few years, hopefully they'll find a better solution than the current notification.
https://www.apple.com/feedback/macbook.html

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered a simple way to hide the call window. Right click on the FaceTime dock icon and click Hide. That's it. You can also move the window by clicking and dragging the waveform area.